# Document.write("*"); for loop returns an undefined value at the end of my "*" pyramid?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, undefined, document.write

I am building a simple for-loop function that returns a pyramid of stars from  number input. The problem is it keeps returning an "undefined" value at the end of the pyramid... here is the code:

```
function ligne(x)
{
    for(i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            document.write("*");
        }
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
};

var num = prompt("Entré un nombre.");
var pyramid = ligne(num);
document.write(pyramid);
```

And here is the result on the web page with an input of 8:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
undefined
```

I think the problem is eiter with the "document.write()" statement in the last for-loop or at the end of the code. The reason for that is because when I remove the line break in the first for-loop, the stars print out in one line with the "undefined" value still at the end.

Anyone could help??

Comment: Because ligne does not return anything so it is undefined! Remove `document.write(pyramid);`

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Comment: Just for additional Information: Don't use `document.write`. It doesn't do what you think it does and you'll soon run into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'document.write(pyramid);` this prints you undefined because your function doesn't return anything. if you delete it or return something to the function it will be fixed.